# Django - passing data in another function to html

Tags: python, html, django

So I pass some data from views.py to list.html (only shows the id in list.html)

And I would like to pass the data of the selected id to detail.html for users to check details.

What should I write in `return` of `analysis_detail` ?

Here's part of the code. 
Many thanks!

views.py

```
  def analysis_list(request):
        return render(request, 'analysis/list.html', {
            "analysis_list": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "sample_name": "samplefile1",
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "sample_name": "samplefile2",
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "sample_name": "samplefile3",
                },
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "sample_name": "samplefile4",           
                }
            ]
        })


def analysis_detail(request, analysis_id):

    return render(request, 'analysis/detail.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<analysis_id>\d+)$', login_required(views.analysis_detail), name="detail"),
    url(r'^comparison$', login_required(views.analysis_comparison), name="comparison"),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
def analysis_list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'analysis_id' in kwargs:
        analysis_id = kwargs['analysis_id'] #here you get your selected id
    return render(request, 'analysis/list.html', {
        "analysis_list": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "sample_name": "samplefile1",
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "sample_name": "samplefile2",
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "sample_name": "samplefile3",
            },
            {
                "id": "4",
                "sample_name": "samplefile4",           
            }
        ]
    })


def analysis_detail(self, request, *args, **kwargs, analysis_id):
   kwargs['analysis_id']=analysis_id
   return self.analysis_list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it will help you